# LibGdx multiple touch events confusion

Tags: java, libgdx

So i have 3 rectangles that act like buttons with the contains method .The first two buttons are just left and right to move the character, but the third one is a jump when user touchDown and then throws a ball when touchUp.
My problem is that these get mixed up when the buttons are touched at the same time like when I hold down jump button and at the same time hold and release the left/right button it throws the ball.

I know that there is the pointer id thing, but it's confusing as hell to me.

Comment: Every touch has a pointer index. If you are using the Gdx.input.getX() or getY() methods, they will return the last touch and only the last touch. The last **single** touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a new InputProcessor to Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(), and check if the touch points are contained in your rectangles, something like this should work:

```
     Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            if(leftRect.contains(screenX, screenY)){
                //move player left
                return true;
            }

            if(rightRect.contains(screenX, screenY)){
                //move player right
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
            if(jumpRect.contains(screenX, screenY)){
                //make player jump
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I Strongly recommend you to use Scene2D for ui related stuff, it may be a bit harder to start with, but it will make your ui coding easier to implement and mantain.

Comment: Are you going to unproject that touch coordinates??

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that I had to do the multiple touch event handling by myself with the pointer id-s , but turned out its done by default.

Comment: Glad to help, remember that touchpoints are always in screen pixels coordinates, as ossobuko suggest,you may need to unproject the coordinates in case of not using pixel-perfect camera.